# SQL 2019 : Invalid data for UTF8-encoded characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

When attempting to run the following statement :

```sql
sp_change_users_login 'auto_fix','ELC',NULL,'CLE'
```

I get the following error :

> sp_change_users_login, Line 218 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Invalid data for UTF8-encoded characters
> The number of orphaned users fixed by updating users was 0.

This is a SQL 2019 with UTF8 enabled.

Comment: That stored proc has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Have you tried using it's replacement, `ALTER USER`?

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server 2008 R2 and then state you are using a UTF-8 collation?UTF-8 was introduced in SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Thank you!. Did not mean to tag SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it has been mentioned in the comment that proc has been deprecated, you can use modern command `alter user`:

```
ALTER USER JEANC
WITH PASSWORD = 'cnaej'
```